PrimeFaces Captcha not working as expected
I want to add captcha validation while registering the user. I am using p:captcha. The keys are setup properly, and I can see captcha in my local machine. But on server, after validating captcha and clicking on submit the captcha resets and gives error:Please validate Captcha. (requiredMessage below) and stays on same page.  It does not hit my controller on server. Do we have to do some settings on server? However, it works fine on my local machine. On server, no logs, no errors.

Fresh Captcha showing on page: 
 
After validating: 
 
After clicking on submit: (The captcha resets. It doesn't hit my backend controller, just stuck on same page) 

I have a captcha defined below:
register.xhtml file:
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="registerForm">
        <div class="card-body">
            <ui:include src="userDetails.xhtml" />
            <p:commandButton 
                type="submit" styleClass="float-end" value="Submit" 
                update="@form" process="@form" icon="pi pi-chevron-circle-right"
                id="sign-up-button" escape="false" actionListener="#Cntrl.submit}" 
                ajax="false" />
        </div>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>


File userDetails.xhtml:
<div class="col-md-6">
    <ui:define name="control">
        <p:captcha 
            label="Captcha" id="captcha" required="true" 
            requiredMessage="Please validate Captcha." 
            validatorMessage="Please validate Captcha." />
        <p:message for="captcha" escape="false" />
    </ui:define>
</div>


PrimeFaces Version: 13.0.4 || MyFaces version: 4.0.1  || Java 17

Looks like its working here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/captcha.xhtml

@Melloware Yes, it is working there and in my local. But it is not working on the server. It shows captcha on server, but after clicking on next, it stays on same page, and captcha is cleared. So what can be the issue here?

Oh so its environment specific.  Sounds like something is being blocked. Is your company firewall or rules somehow blocking the captcha traffic?  Checked F12 Console to see if there are any errors?  Check F12 Network tab and watch the network traffic and compare the request/response to your working local request/response?

@Melloware I checked it, everything looks fine. I compared Network, and Console logs on server, and local, both were identical. What is alternative for captcha in primefaces?

I know a lot of people complain Google reCaptcha is blocked in some countries so in PF 15.0.0 its going to support hCaptcha too: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/11575

@Melloware , just an update, I also tried changing the CSP Policies in web.xml as below: FROM:
<param-name>primefaces.CSP_POLICY</param-name> <param-value>script-src 'self' https: *.googleapis.com</param-value>
TO:
<param-name>primefaces.CSP</param-name> <param-value>false</param-value>
in , in both the cases, application was behaving in same way. It didn't worked.

OK with CSP = false then you know the issue isn't CSP related...

@Melloware I had faced other issue as well in <p:media> It works fine with html2pdf but when I uploaded files and previewed it, it didn't show anything. Just blank screen. Here is that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78799540/show-pdf-file-uploaded-by-user-in-primefaces-spring-boot
Maybe you can fix this too in next update.

I found another way for captcha, and the solution to this problem.
I am using Java Captcha Generator (GitHub Project) by mewebstudio.
It works as expected, and is not dependent on javax/jakarta.
Captcha image: 
It is highly customizable. Thanks!
