Show pdf file uploaded by user in PrimeFaces
I have a widget to upload a file, and I want to preview the file after upload. I am using p:media tag but it is not showing the uploaded pdf file.
However, I have another widget where there is an option to view page contents in pdf (using html2pdf) that is working fine (Even it has p:mediatag)
The controller handling file uploader, and viewing it is SessionScoped
Code for reference:
<h:panelGroup id="uploadPanel">
    <p:fileUpload 
        id="fileUploader" listener="#{Cntrl.handleFileUpload}"
        sizeLimit="30000" required="true"
        label="Attach Files" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/i">
    </p:fileUpload>
</h:panelGroup>

<!-- Preview uploaded file-->
<h:panelGroup>
    <p:media 
        value="#{Cntrl.relativeFileName}" 
        width="100%" height="550px" 
        player="pdf" cache="false" >
        <h:outputText 
            value="Your browser can't display the file." 
            escape="false" />
    </p:media>
</h:panelGroup>

Versions of libraries: 
PrimeFaces: 13.x.x, Java 17, Sprint Boot: 3.x.x

p:media is a little funky and old.   DocumentViewer from PFE is the way to go. Also Media works fine here in the showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml

I fixed it by using <pe:documentViewer>
Refer: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/documentviewer/basic.jsf
